# MVC Code First C# Retrieve Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Ok So I am just simply needing good instructional pages on how to design a Class for retrieving data from the database. 
I can find information all over on how to take an existing database and create an Entity Framework from it but I am trying to do code first.

I am able to insert Data (although I am not 100% sure how that is working) I just cannot seem to figure out how to pull the data from the database using the class(Model) that is created and display that data on a Razor page.

I have no problem with doing the studying and learning this but I am having a terrible time at finding good information that will just do a true walk through of this process.

Once again I am not looking for the Entity Framework.

Thank you for all of the help you can provide.

Comment: Have a look at this link on ScottGu's blog [Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) This should help you get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of tutorials out there in the internet.  Here is a small example to pull your data from table and show in the view.

Assuming you have a model class called User like this

```
public class User
{
  public int ID { set;get;}
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
}
```

Add properties like this to your `DataContext` class for each of your model entities. The property is of type `DbSet`.

```
public class YourDataContext: DbContext
{
  public DbSet<User> Users {set;get;}  
}
```

Then in your controller action method, you can create an instance of your DBContext class and access its `Users` property. Pass that to our view.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    YourDBContext db=new YourDBContext();
    var users=db.Users.ToList();
    return View(users)
  }
}
```

Have an index.cshtml view like this under `Views/User` folder.

```
@model IEnumerable User

@foreach(var user in Model)
{
   <p>@user.FirstName</p>
}
```

Comment: darn I want to click the check on both of these due to both are on point and answered my question.